# AWK or sed need to remove lines from output if a certain pattern is found

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I need to launch something, to verify a file.
A text separated in two fields by a comma, 
on the second field we may find `/*/*/*` which is data I want.
I want to discard `/*/*` only

Input file

```
\\CIFSERVER1\Share1,/fs1_casa/c/share1
\\CIFSERVER1\Share2,/fs2_casa/c/share2
\\CIFSERVER1\Share3,/fs1_casa/c/share3
\\EDULIN\edu,/edu1
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs1_casa
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs2_casa
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs3_casa
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs1_casa
```

Output should be:

```
\\CIFSERVER1\Share1,/fs1_casa/c/share1
\\CIFSERVER1\Share2,/fs2_casa/c/share2
\\CIFSERVER1\Share3,/fs1_casa/c/share3
```

What should be removed?

```
\\EDULIN\edu,/edu1
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs1_casa
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs2_casa
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs3_casa
\\CIFSERVER2\root,/fs1_casa
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to discard every line that has only a single `/` after the `,`?

Comment: Keep three (or more?) slashes; remove one or two slashes.  I think.  The `*` in the notation is shell glob notation rather than more general regular expression notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to print all lines that contain more than 3 `/` after a single `,` you could just do:

```
sed -n '\@,.*/.*/.*/@p' input
```

To restrict to those lines containing exactly 3 `/`:

```
sed -n '\@,\([^/]*/\)\{3\}[^/]*$@p' input
```

If you must restrict the search to the second field (eg, there may be more than 1 comma):

```
awk '$2 ~ /[/].*[/].*[/]/' FS=, input
```

or

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /\/.*\/.*\//'  input
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want three or more slashes after a comma,

```
grep ',/.*/.*/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep those entries which have 3 or more slashes after the comma, removing those lines with two or less, then I'd use:

```
sed -n '/[^,]*,\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\//p'
```

The `-n` suppresses normal printing.  The pattern looks for slash followed by non-slashes, another slash, more non-slashes, and another slash and prints it.  If you must have a character after the third slash, add `[^/]` after the third `\/` in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

With only two fields, this is easily done with grep: retain only the lines that have three `/` characters after the comma.

```
grep ',/.*/.*/'
```

With more fields, while grep or sed would work, it's easier with awk.

```
awk -F , '$2 ~ /(\/.*){3}/ {print}'
```